# Error in asp.net core2.0 web api project

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

Getting the below error when I run the api in IIS Express or console or docker. I'm suspecting it has something to do with the bad visual studio 2017 update to 15.5.4 as I had received this warning: Couldn't uninstall Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.CoreClr.x64

**BadImageFormatException: Invalid number of sections in declared in PE header.**

Stack Trace
    System.Reflection.PortableExecutable.PEHeaders.ReadSectionHeaders(ref PEBinaryReader reader)
System.Reflection.PortableExecutable.PEHeaders..ctor(Stream peStream, int size, bool isLoadedImage)
System.Reflection.PortableExecutable.PEReader..ctor(Stream peStream, PEStreamOptions options, int size)
System.Reflection.PortableExecutable.PEReader..ctor(Stream peStream, PEStreamOptions options)
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ModuleMetadata.CreateFromStream(Stream peStream, PEStreamOptions options)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.MetadataReferenceFeatureProvider.CreateMetadataReference(string path)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.MetadataReferenceFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable parts, MetadataReferenceFeature feature)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature(TFeature feature)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorReferenceManager.GetCompilationReferences()
System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(ref T target, ref bool initialized, ref object syncLock, Func valueFactory)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorReferenceManager.get_CompilationReferences()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.LazyMetadataReferenceFeature.get_References()
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.CompilationTagHelperFeature.GetDescriptors()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorTagHelperBinderPhase.ExecuteCore(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorEnginePhaseBase.Execute(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorEngine.Process(RazorCodeDocument document)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorTemplateEngine.GenerateCode(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(string relativePath)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.CreateCacheEntry(string normalizedPath)
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider.CreateFactory(string relativePath)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.CreateCacheResult(HashSet expirationTokens, string relativePath, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.OnCacheMiss(ViewLocationExpanderContext expanderContext, ViewLocationCacheKey cacheKey)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.LocatePageFromViewLocations(ActionContext actionContext, string pageName, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, string viewName, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.CompositeViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, string viewName, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor.FindView(ActionContext actionContext, ViewResult viewResult)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult+d__26.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__19.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__24.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__22.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__17.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__15.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware+d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware+d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware+d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+d__7.MoveNext()

**UPDATE**

Inspite of reinstalling VS2017 I'm still seeing the same error. Any help will be truly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: have you tried cleaning? also, does it happen on the latest version?

Comment: Hey Neville, thanks so much for your response. I upgraded/repaired my visual studio 2017, selected Core Runtime as one of the individual options during the installation. and also repaired/reinstalled the asp.net core 2.0 sdk to get it working.